# Setting environment variables in .screenrc

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to write a .screenrc file that I can use to set up for a developing on a particular project - It will start a few screens, cd to the right places, open up the right files in an editor, and set some environment variables needed for testing.

I can't get the environment setup to work.. I've tried putting this in `` `~/.screenrc ``:

```
setenv PATH ~/src/my_proj/bin/:$PATH
```

This doesn't work, and I think the problem is that after `screen` sets `PATH`, the regular shell initialization scripts kick in and change it on me.

I don't want to disable the regular shell init scripts. Is there any way to make screen `setenv` *after* the shell is initialized? Or alternatively, can screen set a variable to read-only?

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it with some bash magic instead. Try adding something like this to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
screen -t "window" bash -ic 'PATH=~/src/my_proj/bin/:$PATH bash'
```

For more details and to have this set for newly created windows using `Ctrl-a Ctrl+c` or `Ctrl-a c` see my answer to a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717641/1413849

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it regular shell initialization stuff overrides this. For example, I modify PATH in ~/.bashrc, which clobbers this.

Comment: It shouldn't erase your changes since they should probably just append stuff to existing environmental variables, especially PATH. The worst that should happen is if they do something like: `PATH=$PATH:/some/other/dir` or `PATH=/some/other/dir` as you'd have no way to set `/some/other/dir` as having precedence over other directories. Is there a more concrete example which causes issues with doing it this way?

Answer (score 5):

for me the line

```
setenv PATH /home/someuser/bin:$PATH
```

in the screenrc file did the trick.

I think the expansion of '~' to '/home/someuser' is bash specific and will not work within the screenrc.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way that `screen` can change the environment variables of a shell process once that process has launched, nor is there any way to make an environment variable read-only (values are stored in each process's memory, and each process has full access to them).

(Well, there might be some ugly system-specific way to do it, but it's the kind of thing Unix-like systems are designed to keep you from doing.)

You'll need to modify your shell's initialization script so that it retains the existing value of `$PATH`, possibly adding to it, rather than setting it to some new value ignoring its existing value.

If you want to do this conditionally, you can test for the existence of `$STY`, which is set only if the shell (or any other process) is running under `screen`.

Also, `screen`'s `setenv` command doesn't seem to recognize the `~` character. I tried adding a similar `setenv` to a temporary `screenrc`, and `$PATH` contained a literal `~` character. `bash` seems to recognize the `~` syntax in `$PATH`, but other shells do not. Replace the `~` by `$HOME`, which `screen` does recognize.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just set environment in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
case $TERM in
screen*)
  export PS1='[\u:screen \w]\$ '
  ;;
*)
  export PS1='[\u \w]\$ '
  ;;
esac
```

It worked, enjoy it.

Comment: This is similar to Keith Thompson's answer, except he recommends using `$STY` existence instead of `$TERM == 'screen'`

Comment: In my case I needed to override `$TERM` for screen sessions to force them to support 256 colors. Seems to be a bug on NetBSD systems at the moment. This answer is the only way I could find to do this.