# How do I get the command history in a screen session using Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, gnu-screen

If I start a screen session with `screen -dmS name`, how would I access the command history of that screen session with a script?

Using the <kbd>↑</kbd>, the last executed command appears, even in screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`screen` doesn't maintain a history of the commands you type. Your shell may or may not keep a history. Since you appear to use `bash`, you can use the `history` command.

`screen` does appear to have a crude approximation of a history search (it merely searches the scrollback buffer for a command line. See the `screen` man page under the "history" command (bound to `C-a {` by default).

Comment: Do you mean from a different window in the same session (or possibly from a different session as well)? Possibly. It would involve parsing the target window's scrollback buffer. I am not familiar enough with screen to know how to access that programmatically, though. You can try reading the man page for information on how to do that.

Answer (score 30):

I use the default bash shell on my system and so might not work with other shells.

this is what I have in my `~/.screenrc` file so that each new screen window gets its own command history:

## Default Screen Windows With Own Command History

To open a set of default screen windows, each with their own command history file, you could add the following to the `~/.screenrc` file:

```
screen -t "window 0" 0 bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
screen -t "window 1" 1 bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
screen -t "window 2" bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
```

## Ensure New Windows Get Their Own Command History

The default screen settings mean that you create a new window using `Ctrl+a c` or `Ctrl+a Ctrl+c`. However, with just the above in your `~/.screenrc` file, these will use the default `~/.bash_history` file. To fix this, we will overwrite the key bindings for creating new windows. Add this to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
bind c screen bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
bind ^C screen bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
```

Now whenever you create a new screen window, it's actually launching a bash shell, setting the `HISTFILE` environmental variable to something that includes the current screen window's number (`$WINDOW`).

Command history files will be shared between screen sessions with the same window numbers.

## Write Commands to `$HISTFILE` on Execution

As is normal bash behavior, the history is only written to the `$HISTFILE` file by upon exiting the shell/screen window.  However, if you want commands to be written to the history files after the command is executed, and thus available immediately to other screen sessions with the same window number, you could add something like this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Comment: This is closest to what I would like, but ... trying to find a way to save it all into one history file. `HISTSIZE` etc don't seem to stick if you embed them in the `screen` command above.

Answer (score 3):

@technosaurus is right. $HISTFILE is written when bash exits, so you could exit one bash session, and start a new one, and the history should have been preserved through the file.

But I think there is a better way to solve your problem. The bash manual includes a description of the [history built-in command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html). It allows you to save this history with `history -w [filename]` and read the history with `history -r [filename]`. If you don't provide a filename, it will use $HISTFILE.

So I would propose that you save the history inside your screen session to a specific file (or to your default $HISTFILE if you want). Then read the history file in the other bash session you want to access the history from. This way you don't have to exit the original bash session.

Answer (score 2):

When you `exit` a terminal (or shell) the shell writes its history to $HISTFILE, so to get its history in another terminal you can type `exit` in the terminal you want the history of and it will get written.

```
cat $HISTFILE
#or tac, less, $EDITOR, ... depending on how you want to "access" it
```

Comment: Is it only written on `exit`?

Comment: AFAIK, until then it is stored in memory up to $HISTSIZE lines, when it writes it keeps the history file to $HISTFILESIZE lines max

Comment: I forgot about `shopt -s histappend` see:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/why-would-anyone-not-set-histappend-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

use this:
screen -L
with capital L
it will store a copy of terminal input and output to a file named screenlog.0
or if you use -S to name it, the log file gets the screen name

Comment: But note: This logs the output as well as the input.

Answer (score 1):

I put the next lines into my .bashrc:

```
case "$TERM" in
   screen)
       declare SCREEN_NAME=$(echo $STY | sed -nr 's/[^.]*\.(.*)/\1/p')
       if [[ $SCREEN_NAME ]]; then
           HISTFILE="${HISTFILE}.${SCREEN_NAME}.${WINDOW}"
           declare -p HISTFILE
       fi
       unset SCREEN_NAME
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
esac
```

My default .bashrc has this 'case' basically with 'xterm*|rxvt*)' value, so I only added my 'screen' part into it. If you have not this 'case', you can use the next instead of it:

```
if [[ $TERM == screen ]]; then
   declare SCREEN_NAME=$(echo $STY | sed -nr 's/[^.]*\.(.*)/\1/p')
   if [[ $SCREEN_NAME ]]; then
       HISTFILE="${HISTFILE}.${SCREEN_NAME}.${WINDOW}"
       declare -p HISTFILE
   fi
   unset SCREEN_NAME
fi
```

And after I have an **own bash_history for all window of my all screen**.

*Note: this not work in chroot!*

Answer (score 0):

`history` will show all the history command.